# Java DATE Parsing

Tags: java, parsing

I´m having a stupid problem with `java.util.Date`.

I have this line of code, but I don´t understand why this date is unparseable with this format.

```
public class TestTime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";

        String date = "Sat Dec 31 10:00:00 CET 2011";
        SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);

        Date lDate = null;
        try {
            lDate = dFormat.parse(date);
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your default locale, is it en_US, etc. or something 'obscure'?

Comment: Show the exception trace

Comment: Be careful using `SimpleDateFormat`.  It is not thread safe.  http://www.codefutures.com/weblog/andygrove/2007/10/simpledateformat-and-thread-safety.html

Comment: What character is that in your `"I'm"` and `"don't"` (for apostrophe)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your system uses a locale other than English you need to use this constructor:

```
SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT,Locale.ENGLISH);
```

If this is not the problem, you should format a date using the same formatter and compare the output to your input string.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see anything wrong with this.  It executes for me without error, and returns:

```
Sat Dec 31 09:00:00 GMT 2011
```

Comment: Without a stack trace, it was a valid effort - and at a minimum, it shows that there is nothing that is "completely incorrect" with the code, and must be something environment-specific.  +1 for the locale suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, It was a Locale Problem!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a Locale-related problem.

If I set a French locale, the pattern does not work. If I set the Locale to be US in the SimpleDateFormat constructor, it does works.

SimpleDateFormat dFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.US);

Comment: Thanks Olivier, it finally was a Locale problem.